# Finding time difference between two times stored in database using sql and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, database-connection

```
string sqlUserName3 = "SELECT out_date FROM status where s_id='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
SqlCommand sqlcmd3 = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName3, sqlcon);


sqlUserName4 = "SELECT in_date FROM status where s_id='"+TextBox2.Text+"'";
SqlCommand sqlcmd4 = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName4, sqlcon);

string q3 = sqlcmd3.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
string q4 = sqlcmd4.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(q3);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(q4);
TimeSpan result = dt1.Subtract(dt2);
string result1 = result.ToString();
TextBox8.Text = result1;


//Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: i imagine q3 or q4 are not valid datetimes.  Also you're open to injection attacks

Comment: Aside from your issue, I would suggest combining `sqlcmd3` and `sqlcmd4` to get both dates at once.

Comment: @Eric hello sir i need to show the time difference between time1 and time2

Comment: The time difference in what unit? Days? Hours? Minutes? The general `.ToString()` of the `TimeSpan` will not give you a very useful value to display to the user.

Comment: Have you opened the SQL connection prior to your initialization of the SQL commands?  That is not a valid SQL command for retrieving data, you should use something like `SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon); adapter.Fill(dataTable);`

Comment: sqlcmd3 time is already stored in database and sqlcmd4 time is current time

Comment: time difference if its below 24hrs result should be in hours else it should be in days

Comment: *Obligatory SQL Injection Attack Comment*

Comment: @Eric it is 2013 - every time someone uses a data-adapter and datatable, the CLR kills a kitten

Comment: @MarcGravell Would you be happier with a much less convenient `SqlDataReader`?  When pulling back multiple columns from a large database, `SqlDataAdapter` is the way to go.  Although you are correct, in this case, it is not necessary.

Comment: @Eric if only tools like ORMs existed that didn't have the overhead of `DataTable` / `SqlDataAdapter`, and if only (for simple queries, not LINQ etc) tools like micro-ORMs existed, that didn't have the overhead of ORMs - in all seriousness, this is an area I've spent a lot of time in; I will go on record and say that in my qualified opinion: `SqlDataAdapter` is a "bad thing" in most cases; the main scenario for `DataTable` is if your schema *cannot* be known ahead of time, and that is exceptionally rare

Comment: @Eric to explain with code: `DateTime date = conn.Query<DateTime>("select out_date from status where s_id = @id", new { id = TextBox2.Text }).Single();` - that is the all the "dapper" code you'd need to write for the example in this question; it will get it *right*, and is quite insanely optimised (meta-programming etc)

Answer (score 4):

There are many things wrong with your code at the moment:

- You shouldn't use string concatenation to build your query. Use parameterized SQL instead. This will avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and conversion issues
- You're using `ExecuteNonQuery` when you're trying to execute... a query.
- You're converting the results into a string which is a bad idea even if it *did* return a date... instead, get the results in a form you can fetch as just a `DateTime`. Avoid string conversions wherever you can.

So you should:

- Use parameters instead of dynamic SQL
- Use `ExecuteReader` and get the first result from each reader
- Use the `GetDateTime` method to get the `DateTime` from the results.

I would personally use the subtraction operator afterwards, too:

```
TimeSpan difference = end - start;
```

... but that's just a matter of preference, and not an actual *mistake* in your current code.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is here:

```
string q3 = sqlcmd3.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
string q4 = sqlcmd4.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(q3);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(q4);
```

`ExecuteNonQuery` does not return a date in a string representation. It returns the number of records affected by the query; hence, when you run `DateTime.Parse(number)` you get an error.

None of your queries are returning a date so it's unclear how you expect to get a date back from calling the SQL you have in your question...

**Update**

Do not use string concatenation to build your SQL Statements. You can use parameters to avoid exposing yourself to SQL Injection attacks. One example would be:

```
string sqlUserName3 = "SELECT out_date FROM status where s_id=@id";
SqlCommand sqlcmd3 = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName3, sqlcon);
sqlcmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",TextBox2.Text );
```

Comment: +1 for sql injection prevention.  It's never too early to teach this to new programmers.

Answer (score 1):

You use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` but you need `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`. The first function returns nothing, it's supposed to be used for queries like `insert` or `update`. The second returns value of first cell of first row of query output.

Answer (score 0):

You should use execute scalar or pass some out parameter to get value. This should get you some value in q3 and q4.

Now to avoid erros you should also use DateTime.ParseExact instead of simple Parse.

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(q3,"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(q4,"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```